# How to pass object in back quotes onClick Function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object

**I am getting this error when passing object in newsClick function**

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

**when passing simple string it work.**

```
   articles.forEach(function (element, index) {

        console.log("globleElement", JSON.stringify(element));

        let news = `
                        <div class="col myclass mb-4" onClick="newsClick(${element})">


                        </div>   `;

        newsHtml += news;
    });
    newsRender.innerHTML = newsHtml;
}


function newsClick(element) {
}
```

Comment: what is newsHtml?

Comment: You are passing object as string to newsSlick function. Try this= >

let news = '<div class="col myclass mb-4" onClick="newsClick(' + ${element} + ')"></div>';

Comment: @Addis newsHtml is a variable

Comment: @SujeetKumar Where is it declared and initialized?

Comment: @Addis That's irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @Teemu, how is that not relevant to `newsHtml += news;`?

Comment: @Addis Because the error is not coming from that line, that line works, meaning we don't need to know the value of `newsHtml` to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to do this task I'll be doing like this. Instead of doing string interpolation I prefer to create object and then append the object to the DOM.

Take the example below.

```js
const articles = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
var newsHtml = document.createElement('div');
articles.forEach(function(element, index) {

  var news = document.createElement('div');
  news.className = "col myclass mb-4";
  news.innerText = element;
  news.setAttribute("onclick", `newsClick(${element})`);
  newsHtml.appendChild(news);
});
document.getElementById('newsRender').appendChild(newsHtml);

function newsClick(element) {
  console.log(`User clicked news number: ${element}`);
}
```

```css
.col {
  width: 50px;
  height: 10px;
  padding: 10px 5px 10px 5px;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="newsRender"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
articles.forEach(function (element, index) {
    let news = `<div class="col myclass mb-4" onClick="newsClick('${encodeURI(JSON.stringify(element))}')"></div>`;
    newsHtml += news;
});

function newsClick(element){
    element = JSON.parse(decodeURI(element));
    console.log(element);
}
```